# Attribute table After Union

Tags: arcmap, union

I did a union of 2 layers, which technically represent the same thing but one is the updated version. This means that there is a common field in both, lets call it A. After I did the union, I opened the attribute table and there are two separate fields both with the same name. I can't seem to tell which is which, could someone provide some feedback on how I can identify which is which? I am using ArcMap 10.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and easiest way is to open an editing session, the field that are editable (white header) come from the original table, the one that are not editable are the joined field...

Alternatively disabling the "display alias name" in the table properties will show the join table name as a prefix on the header